# Guarantee `n` seconds between emit without waiting initially

Tags: rxjs

Given an event stream like (each `-` is `10ms`)

```
--A-B--C-D
```

With `debounceTime(20)` we get

```
-----------D
```

With `throttleTime(20)` we get

```
--A----C--
```

With `throttleTime(20, undefined, {leading: true, trailing: true}` we get

```
--A----CD
```

How can I instead guarantee that I have that much time between each emit, so for example with `20ms`

```
--A-----C--D
```

In general the `throttleTime` with the `trailing: true` gets closest, but it can sometimes cause the `trailing` output to be too close to the `leading` output.

Sample code can be found on [rxviz.com](https://rxviz.com/v/rOW5Wam8)

Comment: Do you want `B` in your output? It's missing in your final example.

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Concat a delay

Concatenate an empty delay to each item, that doesn't emit anything and only completes after a given time.

```js
const { EMTPY, of, concat } = Rx;
const { concatMap, delay } = RxOperators;

event$.pipe(
  concatMap(item => concat(of(item), EMPTY.pipe(delay(20))))
);
```

[image]

### 2. ConcatMap to a timer

Map every item to a timer that starts with the given item and completes after a given amount of time. The next item will be emitted when the timer completes. Values emitted by the timer itself are ignored.

```js
const { timer } = Rx;
const { concatMap, ignoreElements, startWith } = RxOperators;

event$.pipe(
  concatMap(item => timer(20).pipe(ignoreElements(), startWith(item)))
);
```

### 3. Zip with an interval (not optimal)

If your event stream emits items faster than the desired delay you could use `zip` to emit events when an interval emits.

```js
const { interval, zip } = Rx;
const { map } = RxOperators;

zip(event$, interval(20)).pipe(map(([item, i]) => item));
```

**This method won't guarantee `n` seconds between every emitted item in all circumstances**, e.g. when there is a gap larger than the desired delay followed by a small gap in the event stream.

E.g `zip` works in your example with emits at 20, 30, 50, 60 with min delay 20.
`zip` won't work perfectly with emits at 20, 30, 65, 70 with min delay 20.

When the `interval` emits faster than events are coming in, those interval items will just pile up inside `zip`. If this is the case `zip` will immediately zip any new event with an already present interval item from its stack causing events to be emitted without the intended delay.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a ready-made operator available to achieve this (there might be!), but you can do it by timestamping each value and adding necessary delay in between:

1. Timestamp each value
2. Scan over the sequence and calculate relative delay based on previous value's effective timestamp
3. `delay` each value by appropriate amount
4. `concat` the resulting sequence

Here's an [rxviz](https://rxviz.com/v/zopZWxRJ) illustrating it. Code looks like this:

```
const minTimeBetween = 800

events.pipe(
  timestamp(),
  scan((a, x) => ({
    ...x,
    delayBy: a === null
      ? 0
      : Math.max(0, minTimeBetween - (x.timestamp - (a.timestamp + a.delayBy)))
  }), null),
  concatMap(x => of(x.value).pipe(
    delay(x.delayBy)
  ))
);
```